# Flexslider field: number of thumbs, number photos and thumb slider

Tags: media, javascript

I just installed the module Flexslider. I want to create an image gallery similar to this one: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html, with a main big photo slider and thumbs sliders (carousel).

I'm using Flexslider field (that means it will create a gallery with the images of the node) instead of Views. I'm not sure how to show **all** thumbs (all the images I uploaded to the node) in the strip.

I was playing around with the settings in the section "Edit optionset" of the Flexslider module, specially with Item width, Minumum items and Max items. When I change the values, sometimes it shows 2 thumbnails, sometimes 3, etc, depending of the quantity I put in the values.

The weird thing is, when displaying the node if it shows only 3 thumbnails, the main big slider just will have 3 photos, even if the node have a lot of more photos.

What I need is simple, create a gallery that shows all the images in the slider and per each image it should shows one thumb. How I do that? And what means the fields **Item width**, **Minumum items** and **Max items**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it from scratch. I created a custom node.tpl.php, got all the pictures with

```
$photos = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_photos');
```

Then looping through all items and creating for each item the options

```
$photos_slide = array(
    'style_name'    => 'large',
    'path'          => $photo['uri'],
    'width'         => '',
    'height'        => '',
    'alt'           => '',
    'title'         => $title,
);
```

and then print the image:

```
print theme('image_style', $photos_slide);
```

You can follow this example http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html in order to know how to set the HTML.